# How does list() in python works for below scenario?

Tags: python, list, function, memory, memory-management

```
A = [12, 34, [56]]
B = list(A)
A[2][0] = 89
A[1] = 70
print(B)
```

Output:

```
B is [12,34,[89]]
```

and not [12,70,[89]]

I am new to python and I don't get why B is [12, 34, [89]] and not [12, 70, [89]]?
B is having different memory than A, why only B's index 3 is getting updated with A's change?

Comment: They both refer to the same list you created, `[56]`.

Answer (score 0):

since `B = A and  B = list(A)` is different. list() copies values of A . it is same as in Javascript B = [...A] for deep copying

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there are three kinds of assignment, shallow copy and deep copy
`list(A)` is equivalent to `B=A`, B doesn't create a new memory space, it's just a reference to A
So modifying A will affect B
You can check if the memory address of A and B are the same by `id`

The other is a shallow copy, by `B=A[:]`, B creates a new memory, and using the id, we can find that it does not point to the same piece of memory
At this point, modifying B does not affect A, but because it is a shallow copy, only one layer is copied, and when the nested `[56]` in A is modified, B will also change

Using deep copy `B=copy.deepcopy(A)` avoids it completely